# Hi did i do something wrong Verify that $X^TX=\sum^3_{i=1}X_iX^T_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Hey did i do something wrong? The question goes likes this...

> Verify that $X^TX=\sum^3_{i=1}X_iX^T_i$ letting $X=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2 \\ 2&5 \\ 0&3\end{bmatrix}$ and $X^T_i$ be the ith row of X.

We were actually asked to verify this using an application called gretl which i tried but i'm not sure this is even feasible and like i said thought the machine didn't understand.

So $X^TX$ is easy enough
$$X^TX=\begin{bmatrix} 1&2&0 \\ 2&5&3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1&2 \\ 2&5 \\ 0&3\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 5&12 \\ 12&38 \end{bmatrix}   $$

So we just gotta prove that the sum $X_1X^T_1+X_2X^T_2+X_3X^T_3$ is the same but i get a 1-by-1 answer not a 2-by-2 like required

$$XX^T =
\begin{bmatrix} 1&2  \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 2 \end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix} 2&5  \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} 2\\ 5 \end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix} 0&3  \end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 3 \end{bmatrix} = 5+29+9=43$$

Which is not
\begin{bmatrix} 5&12 \\ 12&38 \end{bmatrix}

---

Update

So like this....

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&2  \end{bmatrix}+
  \begin{bmatrix} 2\\ 5 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2&5  \end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0&3  \end{bmatrix} $$

$$
  \begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\ 2&4 \end{bmatrix}+
  \begin{bmatrix} 4&10\\ 10&25 \end{bmatrix}+
  \begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\ 0&9 \end{bmatrix}=
  \begin{bmatrix} 5&12\\ 12&38 \end{bmatrix}
$$

As required thanks a lot to @Ahmed_Hussein

Comment: Because a vector is expressed as a column, and its transpose as a row.

Comment: Oh i was supposed to do this? $XX^T =
  \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&2  \end{bmatrix}+
  \begin{bmatrix} 2\\ 5 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2&5  \end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0&3  \end{bmatrix} $

Comment: Yep ${{{{}}}} {}$

Answer (score 0):

Haha since i obviously can't read it has been pointed out to me that i had mixed up the order of multiplication and was able to find the correct slution.

Update

So like this....

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&2  \end{bmatrix}+
  \begin{bmatrix} 2\\ 5 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2&5  \end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 3 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 0&3  \end{bmatrix} $$

$$
  \begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\ 2&4 \end{bmatrix}+
  \begin{bmatrix} 4&10\\ 10&25 \end{bmatrix}+
  \begin{bmatrix} 0&0\\ 0&9 \end{bmatrix}=
  \begin{bmatrix} 5&12\\ 12&38 \end{bmatrix}
$$

As required thanks a lot to @Ahmed_Hussein